# Is this variant of the Stable Roommate problem NP-hard?

Tags: computational-complexity, operations-research

I want to organize $2n$ people ${A, B, C, \dots}$ in pairs. Each people rates every other one with an integer number going from 0 to 10. The ratings may not be reciprocal (i.e., A may rate B a 10, and B rates A a 3). Ratings are given as  a matrix. Here is an example :

```
    A B C  D
   ---------
 A    0 6 10 
 B  3   7  2
 C  3 9    4
 D  7 8 4
```

I want to find a matching that maximizes :
variant a) the sum of the rating in couples.
variant b) the minimum of the ratings in couples.

With the matrix above, if I match A with B and C with D, I have a score of 11 with variant (a), and 0 with variant (b).

This looks like a simpler case of stable roommate problem. Is this variant NP-hard?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Hmm. Actually, this seems that this can be reduced to a Maximum Weighted Matching problem (on a complete graph), which is $O(n^3)$.